# Scrapy commandline tool not installed by pip

Tags: python, command-line, path, scrapy, pip

I installed scrapy via `sudo pip install scrapy`. It installed the python modules into site-packages and I can import scrapy in my python environment. However, attempting to use the command line tool throws an error:

```
scrapy startproject demo
```

has error `The program 'scrapy' is not currently installed.` and tells me to install python-scrapy.

`whereis scrapy` has no output. Got tired of trying to track down the install path, so I ran `find -name "*crap*"`, which also turned up nothing useful. It seems that the commandline tool wasn't installed by pip. What am I missing with this pip install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question of what's wrong with the pip install, but to anyone with a working scrapy package but non-functional commandline command, you can create a script to run scrapy command line tool for you:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
# path to python 2.7 (python 3 doesn't work well with scrapy atm)
import sys
import scrapy.cmdline

sys.exit(scrapy.cmdline.execute())
```

saved in a file (with execute permissions) called `scrapy` somewhere in your $PATH.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is `sudo pip install scrapy` installs scrapy in a directory not accessible by the current user, if you are not root.

You need to remove scrapy first `sudo pip uninstall scrapy` then reinstall with the `-H` sudo flag `sudo -H pip install scrapy` this will make it such that your command line can detect the scrapy installation.

Answer (score 4):

This also does not answer the question *why* is `scrapy` command line tool not available, but if scrapy is importable as you comment, you can use:

```
$ python -m scrapy.cmdline version -v
$ python -m scrapy.cmdline shell <url>
```

`scrapy` is an alias to this in fact, as specified in [Scrapy's `setup.py` entry_points](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/setup.py#L23) section, and should have been setup by `pip install`.

Comment: OP here. I've just installed shub, a web-scraping utility, with pip. Same problem. Had to write another script.

Comment: This was a great solution, so I decided to go a step further. I edited my ~/.zshrc (could be ~/.bashrc for you), and added the following line:

alias scrapy="python -m scrapy.cmdline"

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether you have these packages or not:

`w3lib, cssselect, parsel, attrs, pyasn1-modules, service-identity, PyDispatcher, queuelib, zope.interface, constantly, incremental, Twisted, scrapy`

I used :

`$ pip install scrapy`

on ubuntu 16.04 and all these packages were installed by it. After this I tried:

`$ scrapy startproject demo`

and it worked for me with this output:

```
New Scrapy project 'demo', using template directory '/home/*machine_name*/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/templates/project', created in:
    /home/*machine_name*/demo

You can start your first spider with:
    cd demo
    scrapy genspider example example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy is not installed on you machine. If you want to install first run these command Which is used to install python-dev on you system

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev libxml2-dev
```

before these commands you should have run upgrade commands

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after these run

```
pip install scrapy
```

when it finish run following to check whether scrapy is installed or not

```
scrapy version
```

if version prompts you have installed scrapy successfully.

Comment: the point is that it was installed. It simply lacked the script for the command line tool. scrapy is fully importable, etc.