# cant't create scrapy project with python

Tags: python, scrapy

I installed scrapy package by using

```bash
pip install scrapy
```

I check if it's installed :

```py
import scrapy
print(scrapy.__version__)
# outputs: 2.6.2
```

so the scrapy package is well installed

but when I want to create a project:

```bash
scrapy startproject Test_scrap
```

I got this error message:

```
"'scrapy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
```

I don't why it doesn't work?

Comment: Add the directory that contains the `scrapy` tool to your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy commandline tool not installed by pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155213/scrapy-commandline-tool-not-installed-by-pip)

Comment: Adding `scrapy` to path or executing it through python should solve it `python -m scrapy startproject Test_scrap`

Comment: I added scray to path but the problem still remains, but when I used "python -m scrapy startproject Test_scrap" it works